# How to export a variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, system-administration

I need to set a system environment variable from a Bash script that would be available outside of the current scope.  So you would normally export environment variables like this:

```
export MY_VAR=/opt/my_var
```

But I need the environment variable to be available at a system level though.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the only way I know to do what you want:

In foo.sh, you have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo MYVAR=abc123
```

And when you want to get the value of the variable, you have to do the following:

```
$ eval "$(foo.sh)"  # assuming foo.sh is in your $PATH
$ echo $MYVAR #==> abc123
```

Depending on what you want to do, and how you want to do it, [Douglas Leeder's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307120/how-to-export-a-variable-in-bash/307145#307145) about using [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source) could be used, but it will source the whole file, functions and all. Using eval, only the stuff that gets echoed will be evaluated.

Comment: I was just trying to do that myself. I had eval and $(foo) except I left off the quotes around the argument to eval. Didn't work. Thanks for the syntax fix.

Answer (score 14):

Not really - once you're running in a subprocess you can't affect your parent.

There two possibilities:

1. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source) the script rather than run it (see [source .](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)):

   ```
   source {script}
   ```
2. Have the script output the export commands, and eval that:

   ```
   eval `bash {script}`
   ```

   *Or*:

   ```
   eval "$(bash script.sh)"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable in file */etc/profile* (create the file if needed). That will essentially make the variable available to every Bash process.

Comment: Put a file to `/etc/profile.d/` on modern distros.

Answer (score 1):

When i am working under the `root` account and wish for example to open an X executable under a normal users running X.
I need to set `DISPLAY` environment variable with...

```sh
env -i DISPLAY=:0 prog_that_need_xwindows arg1 arg2
```

Comment: The answer is still incomplete without eval statement as in accepted answer. The upvote is for a fair alternative to echo,

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use source instead of running the executable directly:

```bash
# Executable : exec.sh
export var="test"
invar="inside variable"
```

```bash
source exec.sh
echo $var    # test
echo $invar  # inside variable
```

This will run the file but in same shell as the parent shell.
Possible downside in some rare cases : all variables regardless of explicit export or not will be exported. If some variables are required to be unset, unset those explicitly. Similarly, handle imported variables.

```bash
# Executable : exec.sh
export var="test"
invar="inside variable"
# --- #
unset invar
```