# ant: command not found

Tags: deployment, ant

I am having some trouble running ant. Here is a simplified verison of my problem. I have a shell script script1.sh:

```
export ANT_HOME=/opt/Ant
ant -version
```

This works. but when I try create another script script2:

```
cd /location/of/script1
sudo -E ./script1.sh | tee log.txt
```

I get the error `ant: command not found.` Does anyone know why this is happening.

Comment: After you `cd /location/of/script1`, type `which ant`

Comment: Are you in the same shell? Did you reload the shell? The export is local to the shell (but you probably now that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're losing your `PATH` setting after `sudo`. Try adding `echo $PATH` in `script1.sh` to see the before and after values. Or just define `script1.sh` as

```
export ANT_HOME=/opt/Ant
${ANT_HOME}/ant -version
```

Comment: Thanks. When I referenced the full path to ant, I was able to get past the command not found error. Turns out I also had an execute permissions problem as well. A simple `chmod +x *` fixed that.

Comment: ${ANT_HOME}/ant version
bash: /opt/Ant/ant: No such file or directory

Comment: @Mr.Hyde This answer is specific to the original question. You need to set your `ANT_HOME` to wherever you keep `ant` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what shell, or seeing more of the scripts it's hard to tell exactly what is happening. But if you want script2 to know about ANT_HOME you're probably going to need to `source` or `eval` script1. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307145/747145). Also I know pipes '|' cause Bash to perform operations within sub-shells which can be problematic under certain circumstances (if you're using Bash).

EDIT:
Double check that you are using the version of ant that you think you are:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Capital A here seems suspicious to me...
export ANT_HOME=/opt/Ant
echo "`${ANT_HOME}/ant -version`"
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using bash. My actual command is `sudo -E ./script1.sh 2>&1 | tee log.txt`.