# Does matlab retain and export variables set by setenv()?

Tags: matlab, environment-variables

When we use setenv to set up an environment variable, does matlab retain it when we open it up next time? And does it automatically export it to shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `setenv` is for Matlab and its child processes, it does not export.  You'll need to use something like [what this SO question does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307120/how-to-i-export-a-system-scope-environment-variable-in-bash) to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable will be passed to child processes. This is how you'd test it:

```
setenv('DOES_IT','DO IT?')
>> unix('matlab -e | grep DOES')
DOES_IT=DO IT?
```

It will not be retained until the next start. You'd have to do this logic manually.